# connection refused from upstream html - NGINX

Tags: nginx, docker

I have an html file running on a docker container with this url: http://localhost:80
I want to redirect this to another port like http://localhost:8080 with NGINX.
I have the following config for it:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  auto;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log notice;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include mime.types;
    sendfile on;
    upstream web {
    server 127.0.0.1:80;

}

    server {
    listen       8080;
    resolver 127.0.0.11;
    autoindex off;
    
    server_name _;
    server_tokens off;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://web;
    }
}
}
```

but when I go to http://localhost:8080, I get 502 bad gateway error and here is the error I get through nginx container:

```
[error] 22#22: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.17.0.1, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:80/", host: "localhost:8080"
```

This is how I start my nginx docker:

```
docker run --name nginx -v c:/Users/ds-nginx-conf-main:/etc/nginx -p 8080:8080 -d nginx
```

here is the docker compose file of web container or the pre exciting container:

```
version: "3.7"

services:   
    web:
        build: ui
        ports:
          - 80:80
        depends_on:
          - api
    api:
        build: app
        environment:
          - PORT=80
        ports:
          - 8020:80
    
    test:
        build:        
          context: ./
          dockerfile: ./test/Dockerfile
```

Answer (score 2):

Processes inside a docker container run inside their own namespace.

Every container has its own virtual loopback interface, which is separate from the loopback interface of the host.

If you want to access another container from inside a container you need to link these containers together.

```
docker run --link othercontainer ...
```

Then you can access the first container from the second container by its name.

Other options are to create a network inside docker which is used by both containers, or have both containers use the host network (which is usually discouraged because it increases the attack surface of the container).

Comment: I tried to do that but I receive this error:
$ docker run --link ds-ai-ocr-main_web_1 --name nginx -v c:/Users/ds-nginx-conf-main:/etc/nginx -p 8080:8080 -d nginx
81c9e792ee939c82e86454252d97dd46b0554fa6b244037fabb842898abd5d36
docker: Error response from daemon: Cannot link to /ds-ai-ocr-main_web_1, as it does not belong to the default network.

Comment: That looks like your first container was created with docker-compose. Then you need to reconfigure your first container to utilize am external network that can be shared with your second container.

Comment: I added the docker compose to the question. I am trying to add this to the docker compose but I recieve error: `networks:
  default:
  external: true`